# Why Variable on SSIS couldn't give the value?

Tags: c#, logging, path, ssis, expressionbuilder

Hello Before this question i already ask on Stckoverflow [Create Dynamic Path For SSIS Logging with SSIS log provider for Text files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15335796/create-dynamic-path-for-ssis-logging-with-ssis-log-provider-for-text-files)

I Follow the suggestions, but my Log File didn't create? why it happens ? is it Logging on SSIS text Log File Connection couldn't changed dynamically? is it only static connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got the answer accordingh to this link : [set filepath from database in SSIS variable for logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15432836/set-filepath-from-database-in-ssis-variable-for-logging)

```
IDTSVariables100 varCollection = null;
this.VariableDispenser.LockForRead("User::FilePath");
string XlsFile;

XlsFile = varCollection["User::FilePath"].Value.ToString();
```

all i need is :

```
this.VariableDispenser.LockForRead("User::FilePath");
```